# Solution of a equation .

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

> Solve the equation:
>   $\frac{a}{ax-1}$+$\frac{b}{bx-1}$=$a+b$

It is my problem.I simply evaluate the equation and I found $ab(a+b)x^2-[(a+b)^2+2ab]x+2(a+b)=0$.I use Sridhar Achharya's theorem but it became complicate . Somebody please help me to solve the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ab(a+b)x^2-[(a+b)^2+2ab]x+2(a+b)=0$

$(abx-a-b)(ax+bx-2)=0$